# Unable to add image (profile picture) button to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, imagebutton

I'm trying to get my `UINavigationBar` to display a circular profile picture in the upper left. I can make it display images/icons with ease using the following instantiation.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: icon, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(funcToCall))
```

The issue is that when trying to work with profile pictures, neither custom views, not image instantiation produce the desired result.

**Attempt 1 -- Swift 4 (Image Instantiation)**

```
let img = originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToProfile))
```

This attempt produces the
[following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R43I.png).

Problems:

- Even though I specified `leftBarButtonItem`, it is showing up in the middle
- I can't produce a circular button using this strategy as there is no view to change the `cornerRadius` for.

**Attempt 2 -- Swift 4 (Custom Views)**

```
let idealButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
idealButton.setImage(imgToUse, for: .normal)
idealButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

idealButton.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * idealButton.frame.width
idealButton.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
idealButton.imageView?.layer.borderColor = rgba(240,240,240,1).cgColor

idealButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToProfile), for: .touchUpInside)
navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: idealButton), animated: false)
```

This attempt produces the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR1Et.png).

Problems

- The image spans the *entire* `UINavigationBar`. It is not constrained to the dimensions specified.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it with `UIButton` added as subview of `UINavigationBar`

So start with creating button and setting its properties (you can use `lazy` variable in global scope)

```
lazy var idealButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(imgToUse, for: .normal)
    button.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    ... // set other button's properties (border, target, colors, etc.)
    return button
}()
```

now add this button as subview of current `navigationController`'s `navigationBar`

```
guard let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else { return }
navigationBar.addSubview(idealButton)
```

then just set constraints for your button (you need to set height and width as you need and left and bottom constraints equal to `navigationBar`'s constraints)

```
idealButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    idealButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
    idealButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: -6),
    idealButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
    idealButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
])
```